# How to call nested function independently in Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-3.8

In the below Python code, I am trying to call the nested function (at step2) independently but getting an error. Condition is step1 should execute before step2, this is to ensure that c1 gets the same value of p1

```
import datetime

def neighbor():

    n1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("n1",n1)
    return n1

def parent():

    p1 = neighbor()
    print("p1",p1)

    def child():
        nonlocal p1
        print("c1",p1)


parent()    # step1

child()     # step2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested function is only available to the function in whose scope you defined it, just like if you declare a local variable inside a function (and indeed, a function is really just a variable whose value is a "callable").

One way to enforce this is to put the definitions in a class.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = neighbor()

    def child(self):
        print("c1", self.p1)
```

Now, you will be able to call the `child` method from outside the `class` scope, but only when you have created a `Parent` object instance. (The `__init__` method gets called when you create the instance.)

```
instance = Parent()  # create instance
... # maybe other code here
instance.child()
```

An additional benefit is that you can have multiple `Parent` instances if you want to; each has its own state (the set of attributes and their values, like here the `p1` attribute which you access via `instance.p1` or inside the class via `self.p1`).

Learning object-oriented programming concepts doesn't end here, but this is actually a pretty simple and gentle way to get started.

Comment: I would like to run step1 and step2 via Tkinter buttons.

```root=tkinter.Tk()
root.title("test")
root.geometry("400x300")
b=Button(root,text='step1',bg='green',command=Parent,fg='red',width=10,height=3,font=('Times new Roman',20))
b.grid(column=4,row=5)
d=Button(root,text='step2',bg='green',command=Parent.child,fg='red',width=10,height=3,font=('Times new Roman',20))
d.grid(column=4,row=6)
root.mainloop()```
but it fails when i click on step2,if i use instance it will rerun parent and creates new value for p1. how can i call child function using previos value of p1

Comment: Sounds like you should move the `p1` assignment out of `__init__` and into a separate method. The class would then either call that method separately when you call `child`, or raise an error if it hasn't been called first. You'd initialize an instance before the first button definition, and pass its methods as callbacks for the respective buttons.